# Store external data into NiFi Registry

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-nifi-registry

Is that possible to store external data (not NiFi flow) into NiFi Registry using REST API?

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-registry-docs/index.html

As i know, NiFi Registry designed for versioning NiFi flow. But i want to know whether it is capable of storing other data into NiFi registry and retrieve it based on versions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of today, it is not currently possible to store data/objects in NiFi Registry other than a NiFi Flow and its configuration (component properties, default variable values, controller services, etc).

There have been discussions about extending NiFi Registry’s storage capabilities to include other items. Often discussed is NiFi extensions, such as NAR bundles which are the archive format for components such as custom processors. This would allow custom components to be versioned in the same place as a flow and downloaded at runtime based on a flow definition rather than pre-installed on a NiFi/MiNiFi instances.

Today though, only Flows are supported. Other data or components has to be stored/versioned somewhere else.

If you have data you want to associate with a specific flow version snapshot, here is a suggestion: You could store that data externally in another service and use the flow version snapshot comment field to store a URI/link to where the associated data resides. If you use a machine parsable format such as JSON in the snapshot comment to store this URI metadata, an automated process could retrieve this data from an external system by reading this field when doing an operation involving a specific flow snapshot version.